# I choked a quest NPC in Dishonored. Am I in trouble?

Tags: dishonored

I choked a quest NPC - do I need to do the whole level again or can I do something to wake her up?

Answer (score 6):

You immediately get a game over if you KO or kill anyone that is actually required. If the game let you kill them, they're not story-relevant anymore; this happens to a few NPCs you can't kill in earlier chapters at certain points in the game. Just continue the level as normal, only reload if you're doing a no kills/unseen run and you messed up your 'streak'.

Note that non-essential sidequest NPCs can be KO'd or killed without a game over. Depending on the character this may not matter at all or it may make the quest impossible. So at worst it's possible to lock yourself out of some bone charms/relics/money. If you choked the Witch she'll actually just warp away and be hostile to you.

Note that there is absolutely no way to wake up a KO'd character. They will stay unconscious until the level is reloaded (via a save before the KO or restart) or until rats/water/you kill them. (KO'd characters can also despawn, but if they despawn while alive they count as alive as far as the game cares)

Comment: What if the NPC is relevant to a side quest, but not the main story? Can you somehow wake them up after choking them? I think that's what @HansNielsen was wondering about the most. I don't think you can wake them up, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Nolonar I had forgotten the sidequests; were there any aside from the Witch with KO-able NPCs?

Comment: Well, some of the non-lethal eliminations require you to finish some sidequests. The safe for Slackjaw is one; he was still talking about that safe, when he suddenly stopped mid-sentence and assaulted me. That has got to be the weirdest bug ever...